# Creating a Tab Character within a Placeholder

Tags: html, forms, special-characters, placeholder, htmlspecialchars

I am creating a textarea which has a placeholder that shows what kind of information should be in the textarea. The only problem is, I need to use several special characters. The first is the line break, which I figured out can be created using this:

```
&#x0a;&#x09;&#x09;&#x09;
```

However, I am still unsure of how to create a tab character within a placeholder. Is this possible? If so, what can I do to generate a tab character within a placeholder?

Answer (score 1):

This is Horizontal Tab according to [this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-punc.htm):

```
&#x09;

<textarea name="textarea" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder='test&#x09;test2'></textarea></textarea>
```

Update: I have just tested it under FF 31 and Chrome 36 and it works good.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-punc.htm

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those worked correctly. I pasted the text in just like you put, but it did not work. I use Mozilla Firefox by the way.

Comment: did you set charset correctly? <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

Comment: I think so. This is my charset: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: After researching several other articles, I found that this works as a tab character: &#x0a;&#x09;&#x09;&#x09;.